# How can I change the GUI?

Tags: gui

I use Linux Ubuntu, but I would like to change to Graphic User Interface (not specific looks like Windows). Are there any opportunities to change the Gnome GUI in Linux Ubuntu?

Comment: Zorin OS is an Ubuntu-based distro that offers a choice of several "fake" Windows desktops that are imitations of the desktop environments of different Windows OSs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, if you want a more windows like desktop that is pretty highly vetted but isn't as strange as unity, try installing Cinnamon as per these instructions

http://ubuntuportal.com/2014/05/how-to-install-cinnamon-2-2-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts.html

Also xfce is a bit more windows like and conveniently, pretty light weight so things run faster on slower computers. The fastest way to install it is to open a terminal and run command

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

If you don't remove your existing desktop environment (no need unless you have to free some storage space) you may need to select the desktop environment once from the login screen.